# How to export results of an analysis in table format into MS word file

Tags: export, list-manipulation, text, office

I'm working on a simulation study using Mathematica 8. At the end of the analysis I'll have a matrix of data containing my results (assume for three variables like x,y & z). I used these codes for integrating labels (e.g. x,y & z) into data matrix and creating a table format:

```
data = Table[Random[], {i, 3}, {j, 3}] (* as an example of data*)
label= {"x","y","z"}
Text@Grid[Insert[data, lab, 1], Frame -> All]
```

resulting in (I don't know why frames don't appear here but do in Mathematica):
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{x} & \text{y} & \text{z} \\
 0.0047326 & 0.877782 & 0.924523 \\
 0.188628 & 0.171809 & 0.317739 \\
 0.775678 & 0.0886559 & 0.336866
\end{array}

I wan to how I can export this table into Ms Word as a table not an equation. Any help and idea is appreciated.

Thanks,
Amin.

Comment: I'm not sure what the *table in MS Word* really is, but maybe you can export your data to `"Table"`/`"TSV"`/`"CSV"` formats, then open it in MS Excel and copy-and-paste from there into Word.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Word's "Convert Text to Table" function for this.

- Select the grid in *Mathematica* and copy as plain text.

[image]

- Paste it into Word, select it and convert to a table

[image]

- You get this:

[image]

Comment: Simon, this works too but when we have a large table as output copy/paste may create typos.Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you create a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/List.html?q=List&lang=en) of lists (which is how you represent an array or matrix in Mathematica):

```
mytable = Prepend[data, label]
(* {{"x", "y", "z"}, {0.15339, 0.622021, 0.932763}, {0.804435, 0.894563, 0.0611165}, {0.786724, 0.980867, 0.766825}} *)
```

Then [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html?q=Export&lang=en) it to an Excel file:

```
Export["mytable.xls", mytable]
```

And then import it into Word, which should be a snap.

If you want to format the table in Mathematica instead of Excel or Word, you can Export it from Mathematica as a graphic like this:

```
formattedgraphic = Text@Grid[Insert[data, label, 1], Frame -> All, Spacings -> 5, ItemSize -> All]
Export["table.tiff", formattedgraphic, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

- [`ItemSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ItemSize.html) here helps to avoid spanning characters appearing in the table.

Note that there is great flexibility with Export:

- I have exported in the TIFF format here, but many formats are available (see [`$ExportFormats`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24ExportFormats.html))
- You can set the options [`ImageResolution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageResolution.html) and [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSize.html) to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you guys. It seems that the only way is to export in Excel format and copy and paste the table into MS Word.

Comment: Well, with Mathematica there are always many roads that lead to Rome. Perhaps you'd prefer exporting as a graphic (see edited answer). Hope this helps.